# Ruby on Rails Filtering a list of users

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a view that will have many controls to filter the interface (or even sort):

Examples:

- name
- active (yes/no)
- disabled (yes/no)
- email
- order_by
- ..ect

For my index method should I pass in GET parameters with the various filters and figure out my view based on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use searchlogic if it is RoR previous to RoR3. In other case, it may be for example search_scope. Don't waste your time :)

Comment: It is rails 3.0.4 what is search_scope?

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/251-metawhere-metasearch
take a look on meta search as well. Both are gems that will give you better and faster way to do search/filter forms.